# Unable to Change OnClick function parameter in Inspector

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I'm still learning Unity and just trying to create simple games to get the hang of things. I ran into an issue where I can't edit the parameter of my method when its assigned in the OnClick method in the inspector in a button. I attached my script to a game object and place the object into the OnClick function and select the correct function but I cannot edit the parameter field...

[image]
Is it supposed to behave like this or am I missing something? The function is public and I'm not sure what else I should be looking at. I'm trying to assign the values to the buttons in the grid so that when they click a space (button) in the TicTacToe grid it sends the value to the controller so that it knows which space will have to display the player's sprite.

```
public void TicTacToe(int space)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean by you cant edit it? you mean you cant just write a number in that field?

Comment: as a workaround you could define a property `public int Space {get; set;}` which should definitely be editable and use that propertys' value inside your function instead of the parameter.

Comment: @MiladQasemi yeah it wont allow me to edit the field. It is set to 0 and will not take any edits.